# What is meant by local time of BM on the boundary $\partial D$?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm familiar with local time $L_t^a$ at level $a$ for a 1-D Brownian motion $B$. I'm reading [this paper](https://dlib.lib.washington.edu/researchworks/bitstream/handle/1773/2219/paper81.pdf?sequence=1) which talks about a 2D Brownian motion $B$ in a bounded domain $D$ that gets reflected when it hits $\partial D$. They say
$$
X_t = X_0 + B_t + \int_0^t n(X_s)dL_s
$$

where $n$ is the unit inward normal vector on $\partial D$ and

> $L_t$ is the local time process of $X$ on the boundary $\partial D$.

It's intuitively obvious what they are trying to do, but I can't find any reference defining what this local time object is. Can anyone give me a definition and/or a reference which deals with these types of objects?